# Refreshing a view from a popover

Tags: objective-c, popover, delegation, nsnotification

I am using Xcode 4.5 and targeting iOS 5 and above.
I have a popover that allows a user to change the background of the underlying view.

When tapping on the "button", it requires that I tap twice to see the change.
I am using `NSNotification`. I have tried Delegation, yet it does nothing.
Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.

**From viewWillAppear:**

```
    // nav button is for background image selection
    navigationBtn.tag = buttonTag;
    [navigationBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:tempImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    if (selectFlag) {
       [navigationBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(BGSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    } else {
       navigationBtn.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    }
```

**And the method for selection:**

```
- (void)BGSelected:(id)sender { 
    self.bgtag = [sender tag];
    SettingsDAO *settingsDao = [[SettingsDAO alloc] init];

    if ([self.currentView isEqualToString:@"New_Journal"])
    {
       NSLog(@"Update Journals Background");
       [settingsDao updateJournalBackgroundId:self.journalId withBackgroundId:self.bgtag];
    }
    // notification to let EntryView know the background has changed
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"aBackgroundChanged"
                                                    object:self];

    [settingsDao release];
}
```

the NSNotification Method:

```
- (void)aBackgroundChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self invalidate];
    [self reloadSettings];
}
```

Comment: Notification and delegate are the proper ways for dealing with the subject. You have to make sure that the popover caller is listening for that notification. I suggest to make aBackgroundChange a NSString constant. Or, make sure that delegate in popover controller is not nil.

Comment: How could I make the notification an NSString constant & why would that be necessary? The caller is listening... I have an observer in ViewDidLoad. Should it be somewhere else, as the view is loaded before the popover is called?

Comment: Make a constant like this: NSString *const BackgroundChange = @"aBackgroundChange"; it will avoid mispelling and most important Xcode can autocomplete for you. Try to set listener or assign caller as delegate immediately after you create the popover.

Comment: I am using Storyboard for all scenes, including the Backgrounds, which has 3 views. It is just the first that allows selection of the background. Not sure where else I could put the observer... as the view is visible beneath the popover... viewWillAppear? I will see about putting the delegate back in and removing the notification... see if that changes anything.

Comment: if you are using storyboard, have a look at my answer

Comment: I did add the observer to the prepareForSegue and removed it from viewDidLoad, but it had no effect on the immediate update of the underlying view. My logs show the image being called from the JSON directory, just not displaying until I either tap twice or tap another background. The background names are stored in an SQLite database, as there are over 100 of them, along with 200+ icons, plus font, size and color info. UserInfo, in my understanding, would not be the place to store or fetch this data from. Thanks for looking regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using storyboard, and your popover is a segue you can do like that:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
   // perform all the operations...ecc
   [[(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue*)segue popoverController] setDelegate:self];
}
```

Then you have to make sure your caller controller has all the delegate methods.

Or, with NSNotification:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
   // perform all the operations...ecc
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
       addObserver:self
       selector:@selector(changeBackground:)
       name:BackgroundHasChangedNotification
       object:[segue destinationViewController]];
}
```

Then just remember to remove observer in dealloc, and in change background method:

```
-(void)changeBackground:(NSNotification*)notification {

   NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
   // I assume you are using background name
   NSString *backgroundName = [userInfo objectForKey:BackgroundOneConstant];
   // do the rest....

}
```

Comment: I found a way to solve this... because I'm using NSNotification, I tried adding [self viewDidAppear:YES]; to the notification method. Now, it works on first tap. Thanks for your help regardless.

Comment: Although this method didn't work for this particular issue, I have found that it works for similar issues. Thanks.